# How do you insert rows with a VBA and then write a formula in them?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't believe this has already been asked or that anything similar has been asked. I am trying to separate my data set based on the values in a column. I would then like to insert 3 rows between them. Finally I would like to add formulas to the middle row of the three that I just added. My Frankenstein's code (made up from others bits and pieces) is:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If i = 2 Then
        'Do nothing
    ElseIf Cells(i, "AA") <> Cells(i - 1, "AA") Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next i

LR = Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AA1:AA" & LR & "").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Range("AA" & LR + 2).Formula = "=SUM(Z2:Z" & LR & ")"
```

As I am sure you'll notice the summation is after the bottom row and is for the whole column.

Thank you for any help you can give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made no mention of what sort of formula you would 'like to add formulas to the middle row of the three that I just added' so I've left in a placeholder.

```
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, lr As Long

With Sheets("Sheet5")   'set this worksheet reference properly!
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "AA").Value <> .Cells(i - 1, "AA").Value Then
            .Cells(i, "AA").Resize(3, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(i + 1, "AA").Formula = "=SUM(AA2:AA" & i & ")"
        End If
    Next i

    lr = .Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("AA1:AA" & lr).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    .Range("AA" & lr + 2).Formula = "=SUM(Z2:Z" & lr & ")"
End With
```

There is also no mention of looking for and possibly removing previous summation formula(s) at hte bottom of the column that may have been left from previous run-throughs but I would suppose that this is to be performed on raw data each time.

Comment: Thank you, so far it is great and it is my fault for not explaining the formula. I would like it to sum the values between the second row of the column and the new break that has been added. So something like "=sum(AA2:AAi)". As you can see this is not my area of expertise

Comment: I've added a [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) that sums from AA2 to the row immediately above where the formula is placed. The last summation formula at hte bottom did cause me some concern; is it supposed to be summing column Z?